# getting error: API resolved without sending a response for /api/orders, this may result in stalled requests. in next js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am using next js to make an ecommerce website , I am stuck because I keep getting this error:

> error: API resolved without sending a response for /api/orders, this
> may result in stalled requests

The error  also includes:

> API handler should not return a value, received function.

I am using next js, material ui and sanity.
I am pretty sure somthing is wrong with placeOrderHandler function.
Here is the code:

```
function PlaceOrderScreen() {
  const { enqueueSnackbar } = useSnackbar();
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const router = useRouter();
  const { state, dispatch } = useContext(Store);
  const {
    userInfo,
    cart: { cartItems, shippingAddress, paymentMethod },
  } = state;
  const round2 = (num) => Math.round(num * 100 + Number.EPSILON) / 100; // 123.456 => 123.46
  const itemsPrice = round2(
    cartItems.reduce((a, c) => a + c.price * c.quantity, 0)
  );
  const shippingPrice = itemsPrice > 100 ? 0 : 20;
  const taxPrice = round2(itemsPrice * 0.15);
  const totalPrice = round2(itemsPrice + shippingPrice + taxPrice);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!paymentMethod) {
      router.push('/payment');
    }
    if (cartItems.length === 0) {
      router.push('/cart');
    }
  }, [cartItems, paymentMethod, router]);

  const placeOrderHandler = async () => {
    try {
      setLoading(true);
      const { data } = await axios.post(
        '/api/orders',
        {
          orderItems: cartItems.map((x) => ({
            ...x,
            countInStock: undefined,
            slug: undefined,
          })),
          shippingAddress,
          paymentMethod,
          itemsPrice,
          shippingPrice,
          taxPrice,
          totalPrice,
        },
        {
          headers: {
            authorization: `Bearer ${userInfo.token}`,
          },
        }
        );
        
      
      dispatch({ type: 'CART_CLEAR' });
      jsCookie.remove('cartItems');
      setLoading(false);
      router.push(`/order/${data}`);
    } catch (err) {
      setLoading(false);
      enqueueSnackbar(getError(err), { variant: 'error' });
    }
    
  };
  return (
    <Layout title="Place Order">
      <CheckoutWizard activeStep={3}></CheckoutWizard>
      <Typography component="h1" variant="h1">
        Place Order
      </Typography>
      

      <Grid item md={3} xs={12}>
  <Card sx={classes.section}>
    <List>
      <ListItem>
        <Typography variant="h2">Order Summary</Typography>
      </ListItem>
      <ListItem>
        <Grid container>
          <Grid item xs={6}>
            <Typography>Items:</Typography>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs={6}>
            <Typography align="right">${itemsPrice}</Typography>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </ListItem>
      <ListItem>
        <Grid container>
          <Grid item xs={6}>
            <Typography>Shipping:</Typography>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs={6}>
            <Typography align="right">${shippingPrice}</Typography>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </ListItem>
      <ListItem>
        <Grid container>
          <Grid item xs={6}>
            <Typography>
              <strong>Total:</strong>
            </Typography>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs={6}>
            <Typography align="right">
              <strong>${totalPrice}</strong>
            </Typography>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </ListItem>
      <ListItem>
        <Button
          onClick={placeOrderHandler}
          variant="contained"
          color="primary"
          fullWidth
          disabled={loading}
        >
          Place Order
        </Button>
      </ListItem>
      {loading && (
        <ListItem>
          <CircularProgress />
        </ListItem>
      )}
    </List>
  </Card>
</Grid>

    </Layout>
  );
}
export default dynamic(() => Promise.resolve(PlaceOrderScreen), { ssr: false });
```

Edit:
Here is the API handler:

```
import axios from 'axios';

import { isAuth } from '../../../utils/auth';
import config from '../../../utils/config';
import { createRouter } from 'next-connect';



const router = createRouter();

router.use(isAuth);

  
router.post(async (req, res) => { 
  const projectId = config.projectId;
  const dataset = config.dataset;
  const tokenWithWriteAccess = process.env.SANITY_AUTH_TOKEN;
  const { data } = await axios.post(
    `https://${projectId}.api.sanity.io/v1/data/mutate/${dataset}?returnIds=true`,
    {
      mutations: [
        {
          create: {
            _type: 'order',
            createdAt: new Date().toISOString(),
            ...req.body,
            userName: req.user.name,
            user: {
              _type: 'reference',
              _ref: req.user._id,
            },
          },
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      headers: {
        'Content-type': 'application/json',
        Authorization: `Bearer ${tokenWithWriteAccess}`,
      },
    }
  );

  res.status(201).send(data.results[0].id);
});
export default router.handler;
```

Any help would be appreciated,
Thanks.

Comment: you need to share your  API handler code too.

Comment: @NazrulChowdhury can u please check it now i added it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you can try removing the .handler from export default router.handler. I don't think you need to use .handler when exporting the router. The router itself is the handler if I am not wrong. If that doesn't work you can try executing the handler while exporting, export default router.handler() 
Also try adding a try-catch block around the main logic of the route handler to handle potential errors and provide a meaningful response. This will also help to isolate a problem, if somewhere within your handler logic some error is happening.

Comment: You sir are a legend,  export default router.handler()  worked, thanks